# Cambiar palabra principio texto con powershell

Tags: powershell

Estoy intentando cambiar una palabra de un fichero que se encuentra al principio de la línea. En el resto del documento hay más líneas con el mismo nombre, pero solo quiero que cambie la que empieza por el principio de la línea.

El comando que uso es

```
(Get-Content -Path './prueba1.txt') -replace 'funcion','#funcion' | Set-Content -Path ./prueba1.txt
```

¿Cómo puedo especificar que sea principio de línea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Añade un `^` delante de la palabra que tiene que buscar:

```
(Get-Content -Path './prueba1.txt') -replace '^funcion','#funcion' | Set-Content -Path ./prueba1.txt
```

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.